# Apple ID and Password not Working for MAC OS enrollment to Intune

Tags: azure, mac-osx, microsoft-intune, endpoint

I am trying to enroll MAC OS devices to Intune. I have everything set up, the Macbook shows up in my enrollment program token, and I am able to start the process to install the enrollment profile, but then it asks for credentials from Apple School Manager. I am using the same credentials as used for everything else, and I even tried to use other admin credentials but none works. I put in the credentials and it disappears for a moment, and then comes back. [Here is a screenshot of what I see - Login Request During Enrollment.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gA2DT.png) I have found that this is apparently caused by 2-factor authentication, but Apple does not allow you to remove 2-factor authentication. The only other option I have found is to use the Company Portal App to enroll to Intune, and this is not a viable solution, as that is for BYOD and these are company owned devices, so the control would be in the student's hands, not ours. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, this is not an issue with 2-Factor Authentication as indicated by other sources. The problem was actually with the Default restriction under .[Enrollment device platform restrictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIGcG.jpg)
Under the Properties the

Under Properties you can edit the Device Type Restriction. By allowing macOS the log in then worked. What made this confusing was the fact that it was the iTunes password step that the enrollment process was getting stuck at.
[Edit Restriction Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FEnw.jpg)